# Is there any way of knowing the content of an IQueryable object without using Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, dataset, iqueryable

I have to work with a given class `"QueryGenerator"` that generates dynamic queries from selected Tables and Columns by the user using a StringConnection and a Provider. Anyways, i don't have to know the implementation of the class but i have to use it and i'm stock.

At the end, the `"QueryGenerator"` returns the result query as an object, the only thing that i know (because i use Reflector on the class) is that i can do an IQueryable cast on that query result. Here is an example:

```
var result = (IQueryable)myQueryGenerator.Result;
```

And for knowing the content of `result`, i have to use Reflection.

So, is there any better way of finding out the content of `result` , and,  for example, fill a DataSet with it?

Comment: Lots of things implement `IQueryable`, which by itself is not a very useful interface for dealing with actual data.  You need to know the actual type of the data.  Try calling `result.GetType()` to find the *actual* type of the object and work with that instead.

Comment: Not sure that's going to help as it's most likely returning anonymous types depending on what the query is, I think you're going to be stuck with reflection.

Comment: @David It could just as well be returning a DataTable (which implements IQueryable) for all we know.  Unless Robin can give us more information on what the return type is, we're just stabbing in the dark.

Comment: @Corey that would be why I said you're stuck with reflection...

Comment: @David Not necessarily.  Reflection to discover the actual type he's dealing with, sure, but only as a development thing.  If he knows the concrete type it returns (assuming it's not a generic) then he can code against that type.  Depends on what type it is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

IQueryable could return objects of different types (e.g. if you query against an array of objects). In this extreme case you would need to determine the type for each individual item in the enumerated query as you access them.

Example code to demonstrate this scenario:

```
object[] objs = new object[3]{ "string", 78, DateTime.Now };

var q = objs.AsQueryable().Skip(1).Take(2);

foreach( var o in q )
{
    var t = o.GetType();
}
```